# How to validate the access token I'm receiving from WPF client in Web API?

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm building two applications, WPF and Web API.
WPF connects to an identity server (now it's Azure AD) and get the  access token then send it to my Web API to get the data.

How can I, in Web API, validate the access token to make sure it's correct. ?
Now I'm using Azure as I said but I should build to be able to validate any access token from any identity provider.

Is there an example or article explain this ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a great article I've been using to implement my token authorization:
http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same probelem.

I decided to use JWTToken

My architecture is the next one

Front <-> WebApi <-> Database

Front is in MVC4 WebApi2

The front will use a FormAuthentication method.
Save the JWT token once the user is fully logged, then send the Authentication Header on each request I do to the webapi.

The front part will only carry the encrypted JWT Token, nothing will be decrypted from it. Only send the token into the authentication http header tag.

On the webapi side each request are cached into DelegatingHandle, Check is the called method need to be authorized or not, validate the JWTToken then do what ever the webapi method does.

I cannot send you some part of my code because this is bellongs now to my company, but I can link you some Internet readings :)

1 - [JWT](https://jwt.io)

2- [ASP.Net Web API with JWT (webapi handler)](http://markwalsh.io/development/2014/12/02/ASP.Net%20Web%20API%20with%20JWT/)

You must then use the  [Authorize] or [AllowAnonymous] tags on your webapi methods.
You can even create your own tag to handle all the Groups things.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask :)

I think this will answer to 99% of your security Questions.

I know this is one year old question, but I hope this answer will help other users :)

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side code**

```
public async void Authenticate(string aadInstance, string tenant, string clientId, Uri redirectUri, string resourceId)
        {
            try
            {
                string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
                authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
                AuthenticationResult result = null;
                try
                {
                    result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync (resourceId, clientId);
                }
                catch (AdalException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.ErrorCode == AdalError.UserInteractionRequired || ex.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
                    {
                        result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
                    }
                }
                ticket = result.AccessToken;
                user = result.UserInfo.DisplayableId.Split('@')[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ticket = "Error";
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**Server side code**

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;

private JwtSecurityToken Validate(string token)
        {
            string stsDiscoveryEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
            OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = configManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;
            TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                IssuerSigningKeys = config.SigningKeys, //.net core calls it "IssuerSigningKeys" and "SigningKeys"
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken jwt;
            var result = tokendHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out jwt);
            return jwt as JwtSecurityToken;
        }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.